# what is the exact meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

Could someone please tell me the meaning of this sentence?

> Value establishment can be defined as the offer of benefits of equal or superior value to the sacrifices incurred by the purchaser for a product and/or service.

Comment: I've fixed two typos (establishment, incurred). Is there some specific part of the sentence that you fail to understand?

Comment: Yeah my bad, but I really need to know the meaning of the sentence, I mean if u know it wouldnt hurt u to explain it 

Comment: In addition to the "Details, please" meta post, please also read [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). And please don't use SMS words like "plz" or "u" on ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Value establishment means that the seller gives the buyer something worth at least as much money as the buyer paid."

Some definitions:

benefit--the good things the buyer gets out of the deal

superior--more

sacrifices incurred--what the buyer has to give up to get what he wants, mostly money given to the seller